# Перевернуть каждую вторую строку.

Tags: devc++, visual-c++, c++

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int m, n, **a, i, j, s;
    cout<<"vvedite kol-vo strok "; cin>>m;
    cout<<"vvedite kol-vo stol-v "; cin>>n;
    a = new int *[m];
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        a[i] = new int[n]; 
        }
    for(i = 0; i<m; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<n; j++){
            cout<<"a["<<i+1<<"],["<<j+1<<"] = "; cin>>a[i][j];
            }
        }
    for(i=0;i<m;i++, cout<<"\n"){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++,cout<<"\t"){
            cout<<a[i][j];
            }
        }
    for(j=1; j<n; j=j+2){
        for(i=0;i<m;i++){
            s = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[m-1-i][j];
            a[m-1-i][j] = s;
            }
        }
    cout<<"\nitog :\n";
        for(i=0;i<m;i++, cout<<"\n"){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++,cout<<"\t"){
            cout<<a[i][j];
            }
        }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Почему не переворачивает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@Relike](/users/16089/relike)](/users/16089/relike), в первую очередь постарайтесь писать понятней. Не другим понятней, а в первую очередь - себе. У вас такая мешанина из ничего не говорящих однобуквенных переменных, которая осложнена перемешиванием, например, `j` и `i` во внешних/внутренних циклах, что и под отладчиком эти макароны понять сложно.

Во-вторых, для отладки и понимания алгоритма совершенно не обязательно городить простыню из ввода данных. Она просто не нужна, но занимает почти половину осмысленного кода. Все данные можно подготовить заранее, и уже после отладки заняться их вводом.

Итого, после сокращения лапши, получаем что-то вроде (не забываем про функцию `swap`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int columns       = 4;
const int col_length    = 4;

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int a[columns][col_length] =
    {
        { 1,2,3,4 },
        { 2,3,4,5 },
        { 3,4,5,6 },
        { 4,5,6,7 }
    };

    print_array( a );

    for( i = 1; i <= columns; i += 2 )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < (col_length/2); j++ )
        {
            swap( a[i][j], a[i][col_length-1-j] );
        }
    }

    print_array( a );

    return 0;
}
```

Так ведь проще понять что программа делает, да? Даже не прибегая к отладчику.

Теперь обратите внимание на внутренний цикл со `swap()` внутри. Ваш код до "причёсывания" я даже не пытался понять, а вот после - стало очевидно, что проблема во внутреннем цикле. Если идти по строке от `0` до `col_length` (у вас: `for(i=0;i<m;i++){`), то обмен значениями происходит дважды: в одну сторону когда добрались до середины строки, и обратно - на проходе по второй половине строки :)  BTW, был бы изначально код не такой "макаронный", вы бы очень просто смогли проследить это в отладчике (можно и в вашем варианте, но к чему разбираться в куче лишнего кода?)

Comment: Спасибо! Учту на будущее!

Comment: P.S. А если ещё вывод массива вынести в отдельную функцию - весь код для отлова ошибки ужимается в пару строк :)